# VERIFIED PayPal IPN Response only in USD currency

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I used PayPal IPN for my website. My Website is in Multi-Currency and language. I have integrate PayPal IPN with sandbox for testing purpose and what I have faced that when I have paying with USD currency then IPN response is VERIFIED and status is also payment_status=Completed. 
8
VERIFIED
0

But when I have login with EUR currency and paying with then IPN response is INVALID but status is payment_status=Completed.

7
INVALID
0

I don't getting what is the problem here so please could you help me?

It is really helpful if any one know this solution and reply to me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue comes from the fact that somewhere in your listener code you are expecting $valid_currency to be returned as "USD", to fix this, create an array with all valid currencies that you accept for payment, and then check that mc_currency is in that array when it is passed via the IPN.

```
$valid_currency = array("USD", "GBP", "EUR");
if(!in_array($_POST['mc_currency'], $valid_currency) {
    //Not a valid currency according to your list
} else {
    //Is a valid currency according to your list
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if this solution worked, and if not what problems you're running into. If this solution is correct, please click the tick so I know you got it fixed. :)

Comment: That is not what the OP is talking about. The OP talks about the message received by paypal on verification of the IPN message just received. Verification checks are down on paypal side.